# proof of Bernstein polynomial approximation

Tags: probability-theory

In durrett's *Probability theory and examples*, he gives the following examples

> Given continuous function $f$ on $[0,1]$, Let $$f_n(x) = \sum_{m=0}^{n} {{n}\choose{m}}x^m(1-x)^{n-m}f(m/n)$$
> Then $\sup_{x \in [0,1]} \lvert {f_n(x)-f(x)}\rvert  \rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$

In prove, he gives following inequality
$$ E\lvert {f(S_n/n)-f(p)}\rvert \leq \epsilon + 2MP(\lvert {S_n/n - p}\rvert >\delta)$$
where $ M = \sup_{x \in [0,1]} \lvert {f(x)}\rvert $, $\delta$ was chosen so that $ \lvert {x-y}\rvert < \delta \Rightarrow \lvert {f(x)-f(y)}\rvert $, using uniformly continuous of continuous function on bounded interval

I think it holds as
\begin{align}
E\lvert {f(S_n/n)-f(p)}\rvert & = \int \lvert {f(S_n/n)-f(p)}\rvert dP \\\\ & = \int_{\{\omega : S_n/n - p \leq \delta\}} \lvert {f(S_n/n)-f(p)}\rvert dP + \int_{\{\omega : S_n/n - p > \delta\}} \lvert {f(S_n/n)-f(p)}\rvert dP \\\\ & \leq \int_{\{\omega : S_n/n - p \leq \delta\}} \epsilon dP + \int_{\{\omega : S_n/n - p > \delta\}} 2M dP \\\\ &= \epsilon P(\lvert {S_n/n - p}\rvert \leq\delta) + 2MP(\lvert {S_n/n - p}\rvert >\delta) \\\\ & \leq \epsilon + 2MP(\lvert {S_n/n - p}\rvert >\delta)
\end{align}

where last inequality follows by $P(\Omega)$ = 1

Am I right?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness.